# how to include my own jar to yarn client

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running spark with:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

I want  to include a Jar defining classes so that I can import and use those classes and method from spark shell scala>

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client --jars /path/to/myjar.jar
```

or

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/path/to/myjar.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/to/myjar.jar
```

or simply add them in `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`